# How to pass value to a vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to pass a value from my web component to the vue instance, I want to use it rails html.erb file,
Here is the element I am mounting the vue instance on:

```
    <div id="app" :purchaseId="1">
```

pass it to a vue instance but it does not seem to work, the vue instance is declared in `main.js` like this:

```
export default new Vue({
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
    purchaseId: null
  },
  methods: {
    setJson(payload) {
      console.log("payload", payload);
      this.purchaseId = payload;
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

After this I want to pass to it's child component, can anyone tell me how can I do that

Comment: the `1` value in `:purchaseId="1"` comes from where?

Comment: I want to pass it from rails view like  this `:purchaseId=<%= purchaseId %>`, if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you should bind that attribute to the method instead of data property and pass the data coming from rails as parameter :
**1st solution:**

```
  <div id="app" :purchaseId="setJson(1)">
```

or

```
  <div id="app" :purchaseId="setJson(<%= purchaseId %>)">
```

---

```
export default new Vue({
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
    purchaseId: null
  },
  methods: {
    setJson(payload) {
      console.log("payload", payload);
      this.purchaseId = payload;
    }
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

**2nd solution :**

Try to use pure js to get that value  by using $refs and `getAttribute` method:

```
<div id="app" ref="app" purchaseId="<%= purchaseId %>">
```

```
export default new Vue({
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
    purchaseId: null
  },
  methods: {
    setJson(payload) {
      console.log("payload", payload);
      this.purchaseId = payload;
    }
  },
 mounted(){
    let payload=this.$refs.app.getAttribute('purchaseId');
    this.purchaseId = payload;

  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Still can't see anything in console :(

Comment: @suvodipMondal try out the second solution

Comment: this.$refs is giving empty object even after setting ref attribute @Boussadjra Brahim

Comment: try to replace `this.$refs.app.getAttribute('purchaseId');` by `document.getElementById('app').getAttribute('purchaseId');`

Comment: Yes simply can do that too :)